# Variable Scopes in Angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I am building a simple web page signup form in Angular storing the data in Parse.

```
controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.groupCreated = false;

    $scope.signUp = function(form) {

        var Group = Parse.Object.extend("AdminOrg");
        var group = new Group();
        group.set("groupName", form.name);
        group.set("groupPassword", form.password);

            group.save(null, {
                  success: function(data) {
                      $rootScope.groupCreated = true;

                  },
                  error: function(data, error) {
                    alert(error.message);
                  }
                });
      };
}]);
```

I am using $rootScope.groupCreated in my HTML to hide the signup form and show a "Group successfully created" message once the success function is called. The value is successfully being changed to true but it's not changing the html view. I am using the following to hide and show two divs:

```
ng-hide="$rootScope.groupCreated"
ng-show="$rootScope.groupCreated"
```

Am I accessing the $rootScope incorrectly in my HTML?

Comment: Just `ng-hide="groupCreated"` should be used

Comment: @vp_arth good catch.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well Angular just doesn't know that you've changed something on the scope, because Parse functions are not part of Angular ecosystem, so not included into digest check loops. Just let Angular know manually with [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) method:

```
group.save(null, {
    success: function (data) {
        $rootScope.groupCreated = true;
        $rootScope.$apply();
    },
    error: function (data, error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }
});
```

And another problem, thanks to vp_arth for noticing in comments: you don't use `$rootScope` prefix in Agnular expressions:

```
ng-show="groupCreated"
```